# Can't capture video on Cheese

Tags: video, cheese, video-recording

```
$ sudo cheese
[sudo] password for ilirian: 
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory

(cheese:20899): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(cheese:20899): cheese-WARNING **: Filter caps do not completely specify the output format: gstcapsfilter.c(348): gst_capsfilter_prepare_buf (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstCapsFilter:videobin-capsfilter:
Output caps are unfixed: video/x-raw, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, format=(string)I420, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, framerate=(fraction)[ 0/1, 30/1 ]
```

I can take pictures, but not videos. I installed GTKUVC video viewer, and everything works on that particular program, so I tried to re-install Cheese, which didn't solve the problem.

When trying to record videos with Cheese, it creates empty `.webm` files in the output folder(`~/Videos/Webcam`). The problem occurs once I hit the <kbd>Record a Video</kbd> button.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: why run it with `sudo`? That's not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

And run:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get remove --purge libpam-smbpass
pam-auth-update
apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Comment: It does not solve the problem.